# front face camera phonegap in Android

Tags: android, cordova, front-camera

I'm going crazy trying to set up the front camera to use an app that take pictures using the front camera.

As I checked in the API documentation it should be something like this:

```
var options = {
    quality: 50,
    destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
    sourceType: 1,
    encodingType: 0,
    cameraDirection: Camera.Direction.FRONT
};

navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, options);
```

But anything happens. I also tried `cameraDirection : 1`, but it had the same result. Always back facing camera.

Anyone knows if this [Android Quirk](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.1.0/cordova_camera_camera.md.html#Camera) its true?

**Android Quirks**:

> Any cameraDirection value results in a back-facing photo.

Comment: seems like it's not working (tested on SGS3 and some older xperia). You still can switch between front and back camera while in camera mode.

Comment: thanks. But i would like to launch front camera when user starts application, not force user to switch camera